# ashx handler post issue

Tags: asp.net, session, post, ashx

I'm getting some confusing results around myCustom.ashx handler.

If i visit the handler via the browser:

```
Token.Instance.User.UserId = 162 // which is correct
```

If i post to the handler:

```
Token.Instance.User.UserId = 163 // a new user is generated.
```

It's seems like when i post it creates a new session.

extra info:

```
public class myCustom: IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState


<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" cookieName="xxx"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a tool to do the post? Does it have a different UserAgent string?  That could be why you're getting a different session/userId than in the browser.

Comment: hmm interesing point. I am posting from flash. let me see what happens when i post from the same browser